# Cannot debug a script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, bids

I exported a package from the production server (.ispac) to my local computer and opened in SQL Server Data Tools 2015 since I need to make some changes in the work flow.  This package also include a script task which I need to alter and debug.

I added a break-point in the code, the problem is that when I run the package from Data Tools, VS 2015 opens but the below error is show and VS 2015 closed immediately and therefore I an not able to debug the code.

[image]
I have been trying to solve this for a couple of hours and viewed various post but no success. 
I already: `Set Run64BitRuntime = False`

If I remove all the breakpoints and run the package all tasks will succeed but the script task is not doing what it is intended for... (this is why I need to debug).

I am stuck and not able to fix the code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" from Script task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997381/runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-from-sc)

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference issue. The references *(dll's)* version on your production server are different from the installed dlls on your loxal computer.

Try removing all reference used inside the script task and adding them again.

**useful links**

- https://mitchellpearson.com/2015/04/13/upgrading-script-tasks-in-ssis-target-of-invocation-on-script-task/
- [DTS Script Task Runtime Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642603/dts-script-task-runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-inv)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78373e2b-b4ea-4ce2-9590-b624a284d538/runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-from-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- ["Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" from Script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997381/runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-from-sc)